# "to do" or "to make" application?

Tags: word-choice, do-vs-make

When talking about application form at the university (as a part of admission). We **make application** or **do application** or both?

Comment: You would typically fill out an application form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a  written request for admission to an educational institution,  for example, an application can be [*made*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+application) by submitting either via an online form or on paper. For example, "How do I make an application to Cambridge?" is the first question in the FAQ list at the [University of Cambridge site](https://www.graduate.study.cam.ac.uk/applicant-faq/applying-cambridge).

Comment: Agreed with Rompey. However, you will often hear people asking things like **have you done the application yet** meaning **completed** it. The same is true for many tasks such as **making** the bed, **laying** the table. **Do** and **Done** are used in these contexts as all-purpose verbs.